erro no import da imagem do pyqt5 pro python
-- coding: utf-8 --
Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'teste.ui'

Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.10

WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
class Ui_Form(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
Form.setObjectName("Form")
Form.resize(400, 300)
self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 81, 61))
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/icon_cheve/download.png);")
self.pushButton.setText("")
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon_cheve/download.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

import icon_chave_rc
if name == "main":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
